# Why is pandoc not able to convert images from this theme?

Tags: pandoc, conversion

When converting a webpage generated by mkdocs material theme, Pandoc output does not export images.

https://squidfunk.github.io/mkdocs-material/reference/images/

Please see below the conversion command and the pandocTheme.docx url:

```
pandoc --reference-doc pandocTheme.docx -f html -t docx -o myDoc.docx https://squidfunk.github.io/mkdocs-material/reference/images/
```

https://pandoc.org/demo/twocolumns.docx

What am I missing?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Although `pandoc` questions can be on topic here, they are only on topic if they are about LaTeX conversion via `pandoc`. It seems that you are trying to convert HTML to Word, which is off topic here. Perhaps [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com) is a better option.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's about conversion from HTML to Word and is therefore off topic.